# Make a small UIImageView easy to be tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UITableView with rows. 
Each row has a **small** UIImageView aligned to the right (a "bookmark" icon)

The UIimageView has a `UITapGestureRecognizer` associated.

```
    cell.favoritedImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.favoritedImageView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

The problem is that to actually tap it with the finger (in a real device), you have to use the tip of the finger and be very accurate, because the image is small.

If you miss tapping the imageView, the cell is tapped (`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`) and you end up executing a show-segue to another view, so you have to go back and try again (not cool)

Question: what is the best way to solve this? **I want it to be easy to be tapped.**

I have some ideas:

1. Create a larger image with transparent surrounding (ie: crop out with transparent background) -- *downside is that I also use this image in other views, in which is not tappable, so I'd have to create two versions of the image*
2. Put the image inside a UIView and make the UIView big and tappable instead of the UIImageView
3. Add padding to the UIImageView (will this work? or the padding is not recognized in the `UITapGestureRecognizer`?)

Comment: Additionally, you can make the cell swipe and add an action button.

Comment: Well I also implemented long-press for bookmarking but users didn't get it. With swipe it would be the same. Users always try to tap the imageView with the bookmark icon

Answer (score 0):

Per your own suggestion, you should create a transparent view that is much larger and attach the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the view and then nest your smaller image within the view.  That way appearances are the same, but you handle a much larger area for the tap to be recognized with selecting the cell.